# How to disable npm's progress bar

Tags: node.js, performance, npm

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283) the progress bar of npm slows down the whole installation progress significantly. The solution given is to disable it

```
$> npm set progress=false && npm install
```

The question I have, is it possible inside a project to set something (in package.json for example) such that I can omit `progress=false` on the command line and simply can do `$> npm install` and obtain the same result as above?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Add the following to a file called `.npmrc` in your project root folder:

```
progress=false
```

It is also possible to place this file in your home directory: `~/.npmrc`

[Learn more about NPM config.](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config)

You can also do this on the command line:

```
npm install --no-progress
```

Comment: how to enable back with npm install command? npm install --yes-progress ?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: `npm set progress=true` or just don't mention the `--no-progress` or set `progress=true` in .npmrc. Either of these would work.

Answer (score 26):

in the later version of npm you can use

`npm install --no-progress`

see
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#progress

Answer (score 6):

While the op's and selected answer probably work well, my issue was different :
some build steps in ***package.json*** explicitely included *--progress*, which was just making my Jenkins builds slow and ugly.

I removed those with a simple sed before executing npm install :

`sed -i 's#--progress##g' package.json`

Of course, if *I had had write access to*, it *might* have been better to remove the --progress argument directly from the sources files.

Anyway, I hope it will help.